# Returning correctly formatted json response for use in highcharts with Laravel

Tags: php, json, highcharts, laravel-4

I have a highcharts chart in one of my views and I want the source data to be ajax loaded from a route that returns a json response.

So I made an api route:

```
Route::get('api/v1/data/{id}', function($id) {
    //Do some stuff and make a key value array with unix timestamp as key and float as value
    $data = Model::getData($id);    
    return $data;
});
```

I have set up the highchart in my view as [in the demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) but with my api route as the json source. My chart renders OK but the data is not drawn. There are no errors in the console.

When I view the output of my api route the json output is as follows:

```
{
    "1317423600": 0,
    "1325289600": -0.17099521359192,
    "1333148400": 0.85133638321359,
    "1341010800": -0.94235521748172,
    "1348959600": 0.37334056741349,
    "1356912000": -0.15089107586321,
    "1364688000": 10.261663055542,
    "1372546800": 9.4860565407533,
    "1380495600": 6.2120398914028,
    "1388448000": 8.7469537358921,
    "1396220400": 8.7985530414845,
    "1398812400": 7.633928980909
}
```

While the demo json output is [like this](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?):

```
[
  [1147651200000,67.79],
  [1147737600000,64.98],
  [1147824000000,65.26],
  [1147910400000,63.18],
  [1147996800000,64.51],
  [1148256000000,63.38],
  [1148342400000,63.15]
]
```

I suspect this is why the data is not rendering. Why the difference in output and how can I return a response that highcharts will understand.

Comment: The demo "json" output is not json - looks more like a jquery array to me.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange The "demo json" is json as well, it is an array of arrays, in json syntax. See [http://json.org/](http://json.org/)

Comment: OK, but I am calling `$.getJSON` on the json source so hopefully that should parse it for highcharts but it is hard to debug

Comment: The difference is that the demo will return an array, while your json will return an object/dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the data source (model data result).

Check this out, if you prepared the data like this:

```
$data[] = array(1317423600,0);
$data[] = array(1325289600, -0.17099521359192);
$data[] = array(1333148400, 0.85133638321359);

var_dump(json_encode($data));
```

it produces the json in the format you want:

```
string '[[1317423600,0],[1325289600,-0.17099521359192],[1333148400,0.85133638321359]]' (length=77)
```

---

So... to fix this, can *could* try something like this:

```
Route::get('api/v1/data/{id}', function($id)
{
    // Load DB Data
    $data = Model::getData($id);    

    // Parse Data
    $parsedData = array();
    foreach ($data as $k => $v)
        $parsedData[] = array($k, $v);

    // Finish
    return $parsedData;
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. My data was as a key => value array when it should have been an array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Your json should be array or you can use this constircutoon
{ 
  x: 1317423600,
  y: -0.17099521359192
}

In case when you use json_encode() set a flag JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK to return numbers, instead of strings.

Comment: I'm not using `json_encode` but Laravel's `Response::json($data)`. I can't seem to find a way to implement this numeric check on the laravel method.

Comment: So after getting json, you need to itearte on each element and use parseFloat() to convert string into number.

Comment: Indeed that could have been an issue but was not in fact the cause of the problem. The x-values were strings as they were keys to the array. In fact what is required by highcharts is an array of arrays (with no keys) the first value in each sub-array is the x-value and the second is the y-value. When output as json it produces the correct data.